# jQuery replace attr scource with var

Tags: jquery

How can I change image source attribute with var

```
$(this).attr('src','' +myVar+ '')

var myVar = "img/image.png";
```

i tried like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that your actual source code? Because you're defining the variable *after* you're using it. Just switch the lines around. (And no need to do `''+myVar+''`, just use the variable directly.)

If it still doesn't work, make sure that `this` refers to the image element you want to change.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
var myVar = '/img/image.png';
$(this).attr('src', myVar)
```

The arguments passed to `attr()` can be a quoted string `"/img/image.png"`, or a variable 'containing' that string. If you pass a variable it doesn't need to be quoted, though you do have to define the variable before you use it.

Also, for a slight performance boost (seriously *slight*) you can avoid wrapping `this` into the jQuery object `$(this)` and simply use (after defining the variable):

```
this.src = myVar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `$(this).attr('src', myVar);`

And make sure myVar is defined in scope when the above line is executed.